# forarray and a \gdef list parameter

Tags: macros, foreach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forarray}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\mytext}[1]{\gdef\themytext{#1}}
  \newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\ForEach{,}{\typeout{\thislevelitem}}{#1}}

  % this one works, it prints
  % x
  % y
  % z
  \mytest{x,y,z}

  % this one doesn't work, it prints
  % x,y,z
  \mytext{x,y,z}
  \mytest{\themytext}

\end{document}
```

This is a simplified example of an issue I'm facing writing a LaTeX class file. I can't get `\ForEach` to work when the list parameter comes via a global macro definition.

How can I modify the definition of `\mytex` so that the example works?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose that `\ForEachX` is what you need.

Comment: @egreg `\ForEachX` would be easier

Comment: Yes, `\ForEachX` fixes this issue for me very cleanly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forarray}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\mytext}[1]{\gdef\themytext{#1}}
  \newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\ForEachX{,}{\typeout{\thislevelitem}}{#1}}

  % this one works, it prints
  % x
  % y
  % z
  \mytest{x,y,z}

  % this one works, it prints
  % x
  % y
  % z
  \mytext{x,y,z}
  \mytest{\themytext}

\end{document}
```

Notice the use of `\ForEachX`, which expands the third argument, instead of `\ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to modify how you call `\mytest`, then

```
\expandafter\mytest\expandafter{\themytext}
```

gives

x

y

z

or you could define `\mytest` differently

```
\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\edef\mylist{#1}%
    \expandafter\@mytest\expandafter{\mylist}}%
  \newcommand{\@mytest}[1]{\ForEach{,}{\typeout{\thislevelitem}}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option is fine with me to use inside my class. By extension, how would the syntax be if `\mytest` would have two parameters instead of one, both to be expanded? `\expandafter\mytest\expandafter{\something}\expandafter{\themytext}` doesn't work.

Comment: If there are two arguments, you are going to need a messy chain of `\expandafter`s. I would consider redefining `mytest`. The chain would look like: `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mytest\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\something\expandafter}\expandafter{\themytext}`